# Replace string sequence with a new dependent string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, decode, encode

I have an encoded string. The char that is escaped is placed between "&#" and ";". I would like to replace all patterns of `/&#(\d)+;/` with a string which is dependent on the values of the digits - `String.fromCharCode(d)`. Any suggestions?

Comment: should this also handle `&#x2014;` or `&copy;` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a replacer function that calls `String.fromCharCode`:

```js
const input = 'foo&#98;&#125;bar';
const replaced = input.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, (_, code) => String.fromCharCode(code));
console.log(replaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a replacer function and move the `+` inside of the group for one or more digits in the regular expression.

```js
var string = '&#65;',
    newString = string.replace(
        /&#(\d+);/g,
        (_, d) => String.fromCodePoint(d)
    );

console.log(newString);
```

Comment: I think the _point_ being made is to use [`String.fromCodePoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint).